# Mysql2 error in starting rails server in mac m1

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, apple-m1, ruby-2.3

I have installed mysql2 in mac m1 using the below command

```
gem uninstall mysql2
gem install mysql2 -v '0.3.21' -- --srcdir=/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/8.0.28_1/bin/include --with-mysql-include=/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/8.0.28_1/include/mysql --with-mysql-lib=/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/8.0.28_1/lib --with-cppflags=-I/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.0/include --with-opt-dir=/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.0 --platform=ruby
```

Installation works but when I starts `rails s` , I get the below error

```
/gems/mysql2-0.3.21/lib/mysql2.rb:31:in `require': cannot load such file -- mysql2/mysql2 (LoadError)
```

I am using `Rails 3.2.22.5` and `ruby 2.3.0p0 (2015-12-25 revision 53290) [x86_64-darwin21]`

I downgraded the openssl to `1.0` to install ruby 2.3.0 using rosetta

I already installed mysql8 using `brew install mysql` .

Above is working in my another project which is running on Rails 4.2 and Ruby 2.3.1 but dont know why its not working here.

I also tried to **downgrade mysql8 to 5.7** and then install mysql2 using the below

```
gem install mysql2 -v 0.3.21 -- --with-mysql-config=/usr/local/Cellar/mysql@5.7/5.7.37/bin/mysql_config --srcdir=/usr/local/Cellar/mysql@5.7/5.7.37/bin/include --with-ldflags=-L/usr/local/opt/mysql@5.7/lib --with-cppflags=-I/usr/local/opt/mysql@5.7/include --platform=ruby
```

But same error, installation complete but getting load error in `rails s`

Any help to fix this error will be appreciated.

Comment: It mostly looks like mysql version 8 dependency issue with mysql gem, have you tried installing mysql 6

Comment: @Manoj Downgraded to 5.7 but no luck

Comment: tried updating gem also ? gem 'mysql2', '~> 0.4.4'

Comment: tried that as well ,gem was installed but getting another error in rails s : Please install the mysql2 adapter: `gem install activerecord-mysql2-adapter` (can't activate mysql2 (~> 0.3.10), already activated mysql2-0.4.10. Make sure all dependencies are added to Gemfile.

Comment: Oke Please add an answer once you fix the issue, Mac with Mysql is always a pain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to solve this issue by downgrading mysql to 5.7 and then installing mysql-client@5.7

Below are the steps:

```
#stop mysql
brew services stop mysql

# install mysql5.7
brew install mysql@5.7

#Link mysql5.7
brew unlink mysql
brew link mysql@5.7 --force

# install mysqlclient
brew install mysql-client@5.7

#uninstall old mysql versions if already installed
gem uninstall mysql2

#install mysql2
gem install mysql2 -v 0.3.21 -- --with-mysql-config=/usr/local/bin/mysql_config --with-ldflags=-L/usr/local/Cellar/openssl@1.0/1.0.2u/lib --with-cppflags=-I/usr/local/Cellar/openssl@1.0/1.0.2u/include
```

Answer (score 1):

I had installed mysql(8.2 version) through homebrew and couldn't install the mysql2 for rail. This worked for me.

Installed Zstandard library:

```
brew install zstd
```

Reinstalling the mysql2 gem:

```
gem install mysql2 -- --with-ldflags=-L/opt/homebrew/opt/zstd/lib
```

Or with Bundler:

```
bundle config build.mysql2 --with-ldflags=-L/opt/homebrew/opt/zstd/lib
bundle install
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way, it's work for me

```
brew install openssl zstd mysql

LIBRARY_PATH=$(brew --prefix zstd)/lib/:$(brew --prefix openssl)/lib/ gem install mysql2
```